# Remove password from Excel files in batch

Tags: microsoft-excel, password-protection

I am going to get batches of 200+ Excel files with a blank password, one just needs to press enter when asked for the password. The system I am loading these files into cannot handle password protected Excel sheets. Is there a command line or other solution where I can just open those Excel sheets with the known blank password and then re-save them without a password?

This password is to open the file.

---

UPDATE:
I followed the recommendation in [STTR's answer](https://superuser.com/a/572186/348859) and used DocRecrypt. I am no longer prompted for a password for these files when opening them. Awesome.

Comment: Just to clarify, is this an password to open the file or for document protection? And what version are you dealing with?

Comment: The last paragraph that you keep putting back should not be part of the question.  It should be a comment on the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Test DocRecrypt.

[Microsoft Office 2013 DocRecrypt Tool](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36443)

To remove the password from a file, use this code:

```
DocRecrypt –i lockedfile
```

To remove the password and assign a new password of 12345, use this code:

```
DocRecrypt –p 12345 –i lockedfile
```

To remove the password, create a new file, and assign a new password of 12345 to that file, use this code:

```
DocRecrypt –p 12345 –i lockedfile -o newfile
```

way 2:

ExcelClearPass.vbs:

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
'    
objExcel.Visible = TRUE 
objExcel.DisplayAlerts = FALSE
'
Path1="D:\VBS\VBS85 Excel Unprotect password\Book1.xlsx"
Path2="D:\VBS\VBS85 Excel Unprotect password\Book2.xlsx"
'
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(Path1,,,," ")
'  
objWorkbook.Password = ""
objWorkbook.SaveAs Path2
'   
objExcel.Quit
```

Comment: STTR, what Excel file versions does this tool work with (.xml, .xlsx, .xls, etc.)?

Comment: @chuff Testing provides the most reliable answers. If I was sure that it works for all versions of Office files, and I would say `Use`. But I say `Test`).

Comment: The OP asks how to remove the password, not change it, so the file does not prompt for a password. Does this DocRecrypt Tool do that for them?

Comment: @CharlieRB Thx, fixed.