# Remove a known Excel password without Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, passwords

Is it possible to remove a known password from an excel sheet if excel isn't installed on the machine? We receive uploaded excel files (2007 and 2010 format) and we know the password for those excel files. Is it possible to remove the KNOWN password on the webserver without having to install Excel there?

Comment: On a web server? No; on archive with a program that can edit excel documents sure.

Comment: I hope the answer will bring some info about the way excel passwords are implemented.

Comment: @Ramhound I think nowadays you can do pretty complex things with Microsoft formats using their own technology (I'm thinking about .net, but not sure). Maybe the OP can do something like load (using known password) followed by save (no password). Google told me how to [unlock excel spreadsheets with JExcelAPI](http://www.ensode.net/excel_unlock.html).

Comment: **But you will need Office installed to use those COM files.**

Answer (score 0):

As you don't mention any OS platform, I'll assume a Microsoft environment.

Check [this SU question](https://superuser.com/questions/572171/remove-password-from-excel-files-in-batch). According to the accepted answer, [Microsoft Office 2013 DocRecrypt Tool](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36443) can remove/change the passwords of any Office file. I didn't try it, but the web page has no requirement of MS Office being installed.